# How to Fix the Error Establishing a Database Connection in webuzo

Tags: mysql, nginx

i have cloud server nginx ubuntu 16.04 i installed webuzo and when add scripts automatic see the message
  The following errors were found :

The MySQL Connection could not be established.
The MySQL Connection could not be established.
~~~
I have root

screenshot :

[image: screenshot problem]

Comment: try to connect mysql in cmd line, and show the error message plz.

Comment: please say what i write on ssh

Answer (score 0):

Set password for MySQL from Admin Panel

Here is their guide.
https://www.webuzo.com/wiki/Change_Password#Change_MySQL_Root_user_Password